# Logging in web application

Tags: java, log4j, stack-trace

(a)How to implement one instance of Logger per application instead of one instance of Logger per Class. 
(b) Can we customize stack-trace to print only error occurred line number and its java class name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd have loggers setup per class because that's a nice logical component. Threads are already part of the log messages (if your filter displays them) so slicing loggers that way is probably redundant.

Regarding application or layer based loggers, the problem is that you have to find a place to stick that Logger object. Not a really big deal. The bigger issue is that some classes may be used at multiple levels of from multiple applications... it could be difficult to get your logger right. Or at least tricky.

...and the last thing you want is bad assumptions in your logging setup.

If you care about applications and layers and have easy separation points, the NDC is the way to go. The code can be a little excessive sometimes but I don't know how many times I've been saved by an accurate context stack showing me that Foo.bar() was called from application X in layer Y.

The strategy that is most used is to create a logger per class. If you create new threads give them a usefull name, so their logging is easily distinguishable.

Creating loggers per class has the benefit of being able to switch on/off logging in the package structure of your classes:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache = INFO
log4j.logger.com.example = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.example.verbose = ERROR
```

The above would set all apache library code to `INFO` level, switch logging from your own code to `DEBUG` level with the exception of the verbose package.

Answer (score 0):

(a) define the same category for all invocations of getLogger():

```
// Create a logger per class:    
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

// Use the same logger for the whole application:
// use this line in all your classes:
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("YourLogCategory");
```

HTH.